# Informix/SQL - Load data from CSV and insert if doesn't already exist

Tags: sql, informix

I am writing an sql script in informix that loads data from a csv file into a temporary table, and then will insert data if it doesn't already exist.

The csv has 3 columns and is inserted into a temp table called temp_table_csv:

```
temp_table_csv
msg_group
code
message
```

'code' corresponds to the same code field in table1 and table1.ID is a foreign key to table.code_id.

```
table1
ID         serial         PK
code       varchar(255)   FK
msg_group  varchar(255)

table2
lang_id    serial         PK
code_id    varchar(255)   FK
msg_pt1    varchar(255)
msg_pt2    varchar(255)
```

If the code in the temporary table exists in table1, then I want to ignore it.

Otherwise, if it does not exist:

A new entry in table1 should be added with a new ID and the msg_group from the temp table. Also table2 should be updated with the code_id being the table1.ID and msg_pt1 being the message.

I have got the data into the temp table and i'm not sure how I can check to see if the 'ID' exists now.

Comment: Does `table2` have an `ID` column too?  If not, how are `msg_pt1` and `msg_pt2` associated with the `ID` in the database?  If `table2` has an `ID` column, is there a foreign key relationship between `table1` and `table2` such that if a row appears in `table2`, it must also appear in `table1`?  Can rows appear in `table1` without having an entry in `table2`?  Are there any other columns in `table1`?   Which version of Informix are you using? And on which platform (o/s and version)?  Do you have the MERGE statement available?

Comment: I'm not sure how important MERGE is — I'm still meditating on how to process it.  You need two separate insert operations, which makes life harder than if you're inserting into a single table.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Hi, I've updated the problem to be a lot clearer. It makes it difficult because there's 3 tables rather than 2.

Comment: Since the types of `table1.ID` and `table2.code_ID` are different (SERIAL vs VARCHAR), it is hard to see how you make `table2.code_ID` into a foreign key referencing `table1.ID`.

Answer (score 0):

Informix... maybe i'm wrong but it smell like an Avaya product, anyway. Without any samples, i would suggest you to try something like

```
INSERT INTO table2(field1, field2)
SELECT msg_pt1, msg_pt2
FROM #TEMPORARY_CSV_OR_WHATEVER T
WHERE T.ID NOT IN(SELECT ID FROM table1)

INSERT INTO table1(ID)
SELECT ID
FROM #TEMPORARY_CSV_OR_WHATEVER T
WHERE T.ID NOT IN(SELECT ID FROM table1)
```

Comment: What about table2?